# Is it ok to store all tokens and owners in the contract storage?

Tags: solidity, gas, storage

I don't know much about GAS usage in contracts, so I'm bothered with a question: Is it ok to store all tokens and owners in the contract storage?

```
contract Token
{
    // ... token code ...
}

contract TokenCreator
{
    Token token;
    mapping (address => address) token_owner;
    address [] tokens;

    constructor ()
    {
        token = new Token();
        token_owner[address(token)] = msg.sender;
        tokens.push(address(token));
    }

    // ... code ...
}
```

What if I have 10 Bil tokens in my system? i mean, this way, is one operation with my TokenCreator gonna cost me thousands of dollars since it requires a tons of GAS to handle those HUGE "mapping token_owner" and "tokens []" which are storing all the 10 Bil addresses?

Comment: This is not according to any token standard I'm aware of. You can code your own token, but the problem is that nobody else will know how to use it, so it will be rather useless. I highly recommend you to either use ERC20 or ERC721 (NFT)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I know, but the question was about another thing. If you look here: [link](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.0.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L233) you will see same issue:
`function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {... _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount); // HERE str 233 at original code //...}`